# Pure virtual function not used in one of the derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I asked a similar question earlier, but deleted it because I couldn't come up with a specific example. I was able to come up with one now. I often find myself designing codes such that virtual functions are only useful in some, but not all, of the subclasses.

Here is an example of a base class `travel` that is inherited by `driving` and `flying`. `travel` has a `compute_travel_info()` function that computes the velocity and altitude. The former is relevant for both driving and flying, but the latter is only relevant for flying.

In this design, `driving::compute_altitude()` does nothing, but we must define it because the function is pure virtual (I could alternatively made it a virtual function in `travel` and defined it, and then not override it in `driving`). Also, ideally, I wouldn't even want to call the `compute_altitude()` function in `compute_travel_info` if it was operating on a `driving` object, so the code can appear to be misleading the way it is written.

Is what I did considered to be bad practice? Is it frowned on to have a virtual function that is useless in one of the subclasses and to call the virtual function that isn't used in some of the subclasses?

Note that this is just a particular example, and ideally, I'd like an answer that applies generically, and not just to the specific example provided. In other words, I don't want readers to be too fixated on this example

```
class travel
{
  public:
       //function for representing the state in bits
   void compute_travel_info()
   {
      compute_velocity();

      compute_altitude();
   }

  private:
    double velocity;
    virtual void compute_velocity() = 0;
    virtual void compute_altitude() = 0;
};

class flying : domain
{
  void compute_velocity()
  {
    //compute the velocity
  }
  void compute_altitude()
  {
    //compute the altitude
  }    
};

class driving : travel
{
  void compute_velocity()
  {
    //compute the velocity
  }
  void compute_altitude()
  {
    //do nothing (assume car is driving on a flat earth where altitude doesn't change)
  } 
};
```

Comment: Instead of having `compute_travel_info` call `compute_velocity` and `compute_altitude`, you should make  `compute_travel_info` virtual and override it in all of the children.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I could do that, and this wasn't illustrated in the example, but what if `compute_travel_info` did a bunch of other stuff that is done in ALL of the subclasses (this is usually the situation I run into)? In that case, wouldn't it be redundant to be defining `compute_travel_info` independently in each subclass? Does this became a "weigh your options" scenario?

Comment: In that case make that common work a helper function in the base class and call that from the derived class function.

Comment: `I could alternatively made it a virtual function in travel and defined it` That's the difference between `interface` and `abstract base'. To avoid the need to redefine all pure virtual functions of the interface in each it's implementation you can insert a `base class` between 'travel' and those impls. Then implement those functions in this `abstract base class`. Then you will need to redefine them only in those impls (derived from the abstract base) where it is needed

Comment: @mvidelgauz Could you rephrase "To avoid the need to redefine all pure virtual functions of the interface in each it's implementation you can insert a base class` between 'travel' and those impls?" I don't understand this part.

Comment: @NathanOliver Instead of making the common work a helper function, could I just leave the common work in `compute_travel_info()` and get rid of the subclass-dependent stuff and make it a virtual function. Then in the derived classes, I'll override `compute_travel_info()`, and call `travel::compute_travel_info()` and then add the subclass specific stuff? Though I suppose this would only work if the subclass specific stuff all appeared before or after the common work.

Comment: lamanon, while I was writing my comment, @walnut added their answer. Do you understand the part _"You can provide a default implementation for compute_travel_info in the base class which is only overridden when needed."_ of that answer? That's exactly what I wanted to say in my comment.

Comment: Yes, I understand you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly `compute_altitude` is not supposed to be part of your virtual interface since calling it through a base pointer is not guaranteed to do anything reasonable if it is implemented as stub in the derived class.

However, `compute_travel_info` does seem to be part of the virtual interface that should always be callable through a base pointer.

Therefore `compute_travel_info` should be (pure) `virtual` and implemented in all derived classes. Some of these derived classes may have a `compute_altitude` function that is called and some might not, but that shouldn't matter to the base class. The base class should not have a `compute_altitude` function at all.

You can provide a default implementation for `compute_travel_info` in the base class which is only overridden when needed.

You can also call the base class implementation of `compute_travel_info` in the derived class with a qualified name (e.g. `this->travel::compute_travel_info()`) if you need to just add some additional work to it.

Or you can move the common behavior into another base class function that is called by the `compute_travel_info` implementations in the derived classes.

Comment: Yes, I could do that, and this wasn't illustrated in the example, but what if compute_travel_info did a bunch of other stuff that is done in ALL of the subclasses? In that case, wouldn't it be redundant to be defining compute_travel_info independently in each subclass? Does this became a "weigh your options" scenario?

Comment: @Iamanon You can provide a default implementation or move common behavior into another base class function. See my edit of the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like one of those situations where I need to weigh my options. In addition, what if `compute_travel_info()` took in arguments, but not all of the arguments are used in each subclass. Like, in this example, I might have `compute_travel_info()` take in the vertical velocity so I can use it to help me compute the altitude for the `flying` subclass, but this vertical velocity would never be used in the `driving` subclass. How would you adjust the design to accommodate this?

Comment: @Iamanon If these arguments make no sense for certain derived classes, then they should not be part of the function in the base class. Instead there should be another function (overload) in the derived class for which it makes sense. Virtual functions in a class should define an interface that makes sense without knowing what the most-derived type of the object is.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an override of the function compute_travel_info in flying.

In this redefined function you can call back to the function of the parent class which would only hold the compute_velocity function and then call the compute_altitude function only in the overridden function.